# jQuery DataTables Filtering for Specific Columns Only

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I am using the jQuery plugin DataTables (http://datatables.net) for pagination, search capabilities and filtering.

There is a filter function (http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html) that places form select elements for each column.

My issue is that I don't want the filter select elements for every column, only some.  I've modified the original code as I want Yes/No filtering only, and my first column contains user names.

How do I remove the form select element from the first column?

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {

(function($) {
/*
 * Function: fnGetColumnData
 * Purpose:  Return an array of table values from a particular column.
 * Returns:  array string: 1d data array
 * Inputs:   object:oSettings - dataTable settings object. This is always the last argument past to the function
 *           int:iColumn - the id of the column to extract the data from
 *           bool:bUnique - optional - if set to false duplicated values are not filtered out
 *           bool:bFiltered - optional - if set to false all the table data is used (not only the filtered)
 *           bool:bIgnoreEmpty - optional - if set to false empty values are not filtered from the result array
 * Author:   Benedikt Forchhammer <b.forchhammer /AT\ mind2.de>
 */
$.fn.dataTableExt.oApi.fnGetColumnData = function ( oSettings, iColumn, bUnique, bFiltered, bIgnoreEmpty ) {
    // check that we have a column id
    if ( typeof iColumn == "undefined" ) return new Array();

    // by default we only want unique data
    if ( typeof bUnique == "undefined" ) bUnique = true;

    // by default we do want to only look at filtered data
    if ( typeof bFiltered == "undefined" ) bFiltered = true;

    // by default we do not wany to include empty values
    if ( typeof bIgnoreEmpty == "undefined" ) bIgnoreEmpty = true;

    // list of rows which we're going to loop through
    var aiRows;

    // use only filtered rows
    if (bFiltered == true) aiRows = oSettings.aiDisplay;
    // use all rows
    else aiRows = oSettings.aiDisplayMaster; // all row numbers

    // set up data array   
    var asResultData = new Array();

    for (var i=0,c=aiRows.length; i<c; i++) {
        iRow = aiRows[i];
        var aData = this.fnGetData(iRow);
        var sValue = aData[iColumn];

        // ignore empty values?
        if (bIgnoreEmpty == true && sValue.length == 0) continue;

        // ignore unique values?
        else if (bUnique == true && jQuery.inArray(sValue, asResultData) > -1) continue;

        // else push the value onto the result data array
        else asResultData.push(sValue);
    }

    return asResultData;
}}(jQuery));


function fnCreateSelect( aData )
{
    return '<select><option value="">Select</option><option value="Yes">Yes</option><option value="No">No</option></select>';
}

   var oTable = $('#results').dataTable({
         "sDom": '<<"filters"f><"clear"><"top"Tp><"clear">rt<"bottom"il>>',
         "iDisplayLength": 5,
         "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
         "bSortCellsTop": true,
         "oLanguage": {
                    "sSearch": "Search all columns:"
          },
         "aoColumns": [
                null,
                { "sType": "title-string" },
                { "sType": "title-string" },
                { "sType": "title-string" },
                { "sType": "title-string" }
            ],
        "oTableTools": {
            "sSwfPath": "../../scripts/TableTools/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf" 
        }         
    });  


 /* Add a select menu for each TH element in the table footer */
    $("thead #filter td").each( function ( i ) {
        this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
        $('select', this).change( function () {
            oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
        } );
    } );    
} );
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<table id="results" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr id="labels">
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
            <th>4</th>
            <th>5?</th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="filter">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5?</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    ...
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can modify your selector to ignore the first `<td>` element. The index of each matched element should be 1 less than the corresponding column index.

```
/* Add a select menu for each TH element except the first in the table footer */
$("thead #filter td:not(:eq(0))").each( function ( i ) {
    var columnIndex = i + 1;
    this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(columnIndex) );
    $('select', this).change( function () {
        oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), columnIndex );
    } );
});
```

If you wanted to be able to specify the column indexes for which you wanted a filter, one way would be to do something like

```
var filterIndexes = [3, 4];
$('td', '#filter').each( function ( i ) {
    if ($.inArray(i, filterIndexes) != -1) {
        this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
        $('select', this).change( function () {
            oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
        });
    }
});
```

Or, if you wanted to control filters by adding a class `.filter` to any `<th>` element whose column you wanted to filter, you could do something like

```
$('th', '#labels').each( function(i) {
    if ($(this).hasClass( 'filter' )) {
        $('td', '#filter').eq(i)
          .html( fnCreateSelect(oTable.fnGetColumnData(i)) )
          .find('select')
          .change(function () { oTable.fnFilter($(this).val(), i); });
    }
});
```

Not tested, but you get the idea :)

Comment: Does anyone know *where* to place the code above? It is exactly what I  need - I just dont know where to place it.

Comment: @Doug Owings It looks to me you have an error in the second snippet. To check if a value is in an array you have to see if it returns `-1` or not. So it should be `if($.inArray(i, filterIndexes) != -1)`

Answer (score 5):

In the current version according to http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html, for one column, I got lucky with `this.api().column(0).every`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#mytable').DataTable( {
        initComplete: function () {
            this.api().column(0).every( function () {
                var column = this;
                var select = $('<select><option value=""></option></select>')
                    .appendTo( $(column.header()).empty() )
                    .on( 'change', function () {
                        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(this).val());
                        column
                            .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                            .draw();
                    } );
                column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                    select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                } );
            } );
        },
    } );
} );
```

But is "every" still needed then? And how to target multiple columns?

Comment: `this.api().column( [0,1,2] ).every`

Answer (score 5):

I seconded matt voda answer, use this code for the first column:

```
this.api().column( [0] ).every
```

and use this code for more:

```
this.api().column( [0,1,2] ).every
```

On the tfoot column which you want to skip, you can leave it blank

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is put this for unneeded columns:

```
<input type="hidden">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("tfoot th").each( function ( i ) {
  if(i>=3 && i<=6)
    this.innerHTML = fnCreateSelect( oTable.fnGetColumnData(i) );
  $('select', this).change( function () {
    oTable.fnFilter( $(this).val(), i );
  });
});
```

This is the best way for insert Filter for Specific Column.

```
i - Is Number Of Coulmn.
```

`<th></th>` - *Tags number must be equal of Columns.

Answer (score 0):

for basic search you can get idea from:

```
$('tbody tr').addClass('visible');  


$('thead tr th input:text').keyup(function(event) {      



  if (event.keyCode == 27 || $(this).val() == '')
      {  ``$('tbody tr td ').show();
     }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the jsfiddle @Avinash, it helped me with my code.

Answer (score 0):

There is even a very easy way:
for those columns you don't want filtering just set the visibility to hidden of `<th> in <tfoot>`
Example:

```
<th style="visibility: hidden;">Something</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way i had done is by giving `searchable` to `false` in `columns` array.
And it works like a charm :sparkle:

```
columns: [
    {data: 'name', name: 'name'},
    {data: 'description', name: 'description'},
    {data: 'company.name', name: 'company_id'},
    {data: 'status', name: 'status', "searchable": false},
    {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
    { data: null, name: '',  "searchable": false },
],
```