# datatables.net regular expression filter on two columns

Tags: jquery, regex, datatables

I'm using jQuery Datatables and I want to use a regular expression on two columns to filter data in the table.

I have code for filter column 5 but I'd like it to filter columns 5 & 6 both. Is it possible?

```
$("#venuefilterit li").click(function(e) {
                var venue = $(this).text();
                var venueFilterRegex = "^\\s*"+venue+"\\s*$";
                oTable.fnFilter(venueFilterRegex,5,true,false);
});
```

I saw something similar to what I need at [jQuery DataTables Filtering for Specific Columns Only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023701/jquery-datatables-filtering-for-specific-columns-only) - but can't get it to work with regex.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can use `fnMultifilter` or if you use `fnFilter`, you must call this function as many times as the column you want to filter. For example you want to filter column 5 and 6 so in your code:
will be:

```
$("#venuefilterit li").click(function(e) {
  oTable.fnFilter(venueFilterRegex,5,true,false);
  oTable.fnFilter(venueFilterRegex,6,true,false);
}
```

If you want to use 'fnMultifilter' you can check this [fnMultiFilter](http://datatables.net/plug-ins/api#fnMultiFilter)

Comment: Didn't work in my code, but it's a step in the right direction using that fnMultifilter plug-in, thanks!

Comment: if you still want to use `fnFilter` you can check this [site](http://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html) and do some edit in `fnFilterColumn (i)` function to reach your goal.