# Search more than one field using search box in Laravel Backpack CRUD

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

How can I change the default behavior of the search box to search text in more than one column?  Sure, I can add filters, but I want the Search box to also be visible and allow users to quickly type in text and have it search in multiple text columns.

Probably a simple question that I can't find an answer to in any docs, but maybe overlooking the obvious on https://laravel-backpack.readme.io/v3.0/docs ??

In a table with fields like id, name, description, url  and a record with

```
id=1
name='kung fu'
description='Kung fu is a martial art that I suck at. Eat more chicken.'
url='https://isuckatkungfu.com'
```

If I type 'kung' into the search box it should find 'kung' in the name, description, and url fields.

Somewhat related question here:

[image: screenshot of the search box]

Comment: is this how it would work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8023701/jquery-datatables-filtering-for-specific-columns-only

the behavior in backpack is odd currently. On some screens it only searches the name field. On other screens it searches multiple columns, but not all

Answer (score 2):

Well, I think what you are looking for is [Custom Search Logic for Columns](https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/3.4/crud-columns#custom-search-logic). This enables you to append conditions to your query string, like so:

```
$this->crud->addColumn([
    'name' => 'slug_or_title',
    'label' => 'Title',
    'searchLogic' => function ($query, $column, $searchTerm) {
        $query->orWhere('title', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 'searchLogic'   => function ($query, $column, $searchTerm) {
                $query->orWhere('first_name', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
                $query->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
                $query->orWhereRaw("concat(first_name, ' ', last_name) like '%" .$searchTerm. "%' ");
                $query->orWhere('id', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');

        },
```